# Classful addressing: Connection b/w routers of different classes

Tags: networking

My networks professor said "Routers cannot connect networks of different classes". For example, it is impossible to connect Class-A network with a Class-B network, using a router. Is this true? If so, then how's the internet connected. I mean, those routers(of different classes) must be connected with each other at some point in the hierarchy. So, what's that point (or device) called?

[image]

Comment: I believe you are taking the conversation out of context. Perhaps the "class" he was talking about is not the Class-# network divisions (which by the way are no-longer used, its all [CIDR now](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)). Can you give more information about the broader context of what you where discussing?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Currently he's teaching the basics of networking. I'm confident that he was talking about Class-# networks. i.e. Class-C for Institutions, Class-B for Corporates, etc. But I didn't know that that method was replaced by CIDR. Thanks for the info!

Comment: I really wish they would stop teaching it, it has not been used seance the 90's.

Answer (score 0):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Router_%28computing%29)

> A **router** is a device that forwards data packets between computer
>   networks, creating an overlay internetwork. A router is connected to
>   two or more data lines from different networks.

A router is the thing that connects networks, either your professor was wrong or he was not talking about the networks you are talking about in this question.

Comment: I've laid emphasis on "networks of different classes".

Comment: All the "class" is is whether you set the subnet on the network adapter to `255.0.0.0` (class A), `255.255.0.0` (class B), or `255.255.255.0` (class C). You can use different subnet sizes with routers without a problem, so as I said before *"either your professor was wrong or he was not talking about the networks you are talking about in this question."*

Answer (score 0):

No, you either misunderstood your professor or he was wrong.

It is entirely practical for a router to connect networks of different classes, and indeed this is BY FAR the most common setup for a router.  (Even your home adsl/ethernet router will connect a CLASS C to a /30).   It is not uncommon in larger organisations for a single organisation to use routers to connect (for example 10.0.0.0/8) a Class A address with (192.168.0.0/16) a Class B address, while offering a.b.c.x - a Class C address through a DMZ for servers.

Moreover, the whole design of IP addresses is to allow breakdown and aggregation of addresses to reduce load on routing tables - and routing tables are typically large lists of directories stored in routers showing how to reach Class A,B,C and subsets of these through the router.